# What are the 2 CD keys provided with the Ultimate Edition for?

Tags: steam, dragon-age-origins

I've just bought Dragon Age: Origins - Ultimate Edition on Steam.  When I launch the game, it gives me 2 CD keys. What are they for?

The [game's store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/47810/) says

> Requires agreement to a 3rd-party EULA (End User License Agreements)

I have no idea what it is; could it be related to the cd keys?

Comment: It's for the DLC/Expansion 'Awakening'. Though it may already be installed/activated through the installation process, Steam is required to provide you with a copy of the key, should you ever need it (for example, in case EA asks for it while providing support).

Comment: Well you comment sounds like the best answer so far; feel free to post it as an answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for the DLC/Expansion 'Awakening'. Though it may already be installed and/or activated through the installation process, Steam is required to provide you with a copy of the key, should you ever need it. For example, when EA asks for it while providing support.

Often games (though, older games, in my experience) would ask for your cd key in-game before allowing multiplayer access. I think this is the historical reason Steam does this.

Answer (score 1):

Having done this myself recently, there is a page on the Bioware site where you can register the key. The second key registered fine for me, but the first did not. I believe you just have to register the second key on the Bioware site (https://social.bioware.com/redeem_code.php) and log in on Origins to unlock the DLC fully

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell that are 2 extra games. So what you want to do is go into steam, go into your library, click the + and add game enter the code and it should prompt you to download the game. This should help. I don't know about the EULA.